# Wrong dropbox "shared folder" icon

Tags: 16.04, ubuntu-gnome

I have many Dropbox folders shared with other users.  The problem is that they look like normal ones and I can't tell which folders are shared and which not (unless I right-click and go to dropbox website)

Currently I'm using Ubuntu Gnome 16.04.
Have anybody had the same issue?

Comment: Do you have the `nautilus-dropbox` package installed? Try opening a terminal window (Alt-Ctrl-T) and running `sudo apt update` followed by `sudo apt install nautilus-dropbox`

Comment: Interesting,  I tried that and here's what I got:
`Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or been moved out of Incoming. The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies: nautilus-dropbox : Depends: dropbox but it is not going to be installed E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`

Comment: That is quite odd, since the `nautilus-dropbox` package doesn't depend on the `dropbox` package: http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/nautilus-dropbox Do you have any extra software repositories added to your system that might be supplying a non-standard `nautilus-dropbox` package?

Comment: I have dropbox official repository, I disabled it from Softwares&Updates->Other Software and I was able to install nautilus-dropbox but I apparently nothing has changed.

Comment: When you say "nothing has changed", do you mean you're still getting error messages, or just that the issues in your original question still apply? (If the latter, make sure you restart and see if they  persist)

Comment: Right, I restarted the computer but the issues still apply.